# PHP Version upgrade without affecting other host in shared hosting

Tags: server, shared-hosting

What are the other option to upgrade PHP Version to latest without affecting other Sub domain

I'm complete new to the server side configuration.I'm working on a project setup at `testsubdomain.mydomain.com` Which need to use latest versoin of PHP 7. I tried AddHandler  `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php .php5 .php4 .php3` it is not working. Our cpanel does not include PHP Version Manager.How to upgrade PHP Version without affecting other sub domains

Answer (score 1):

Better to update your cpanel version to the latest one as well as update Easy Apache 3 to Easy Apache 4 which will then have the PHP multi manager facility with which you will have the PHP 7.x version installed and you can easily change the php version for a specific domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It is because your are using people services. Especially cPanel, it is control by user account. The PHP version is bind to the user account. This is how cPanel works. https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA4/PHP+Home#PHPHome-Vendor-providedPHPversions

If you want different version in one server, I suggest you have a dedicated server or VPS then installed with docker. Like that you have different PHP version environment.